# Run Linux (Mint / Ubuntu / Debian) GNOME system notifications from log file text

Tags: shell, ubuntu, linux-mint, gnome, cinnamon

I am running Linux Mint 20.2 (Mint comes from ubuntu via Debian).

I have a log file from abraunegg's onedrive client that outputs stuff like this (onedrive client is running constantly via systemd):

```
2022-Jan-16 14:40:14.9203443    Starting a sync with OneDrive
2022-Jan-16 14:40:14.9206537    Syncing changes from OneDrive ...
2022-Jan-16 14:40:16.1507118    Sync with OneDrive is complete
2022-Jan-16 14:40:40.7630634    Retry sync count: 1: Cannot open file `./Untitled Document' in mode `rb' (No such file or directory)
2022-Jan-16 14:40:41.4198398    Moving ./Untitled Document to ./linux_mint_is_great.txt
2022-Jan-16 14:40:41.9391852    Uploading new file ./linux_mint_is_great.txt ... done.
2022-Jan-16 14:40:45.4773655    Uploading new file ./linux_mint_is_great (copy).txt ... done.
2022-Jan-16 14:40:47.8734736    Uploading new file ./linux_mint_is_great (another copy).txt ... done.
2022-Jan-16 14:40:48.1857814    Starting a sync with OneDrive
2022-Jan-16 14:40:48.186048 Syncing changes from OneDrive ...
2022-Jan-16 14:40:49.4558493    Sync with OneDrive is complete
2022-Jan-16 14:40:59.2265195    Deleting item from OneDrive: ./linux_mint_is_great (copy).txt
2022-Jan-16 14:40:59.3837201    Deleting item from OneDrive: ./linux_mint_is_great.txt
2022-Jan-16 14:40:59.5461714    Deleting item from OneDrive: ./linux_mint_is_great (another copy).txt
```

The client is configured to output SOME log events to system notifications, but only very critical ones (e.g. can't connect to onedrive), and there is no option to notify on other issues (and no plans to do so).

My log file with all events is in `home/john/.config/onedrive/john.onedrive.log`

What I would like is to configure my system to display notifications for events in the log file above like "Uploading new file ...", "Deleting item from OneDrive...", and other matters I want to display (the alternative is running -tail on the log... but that displays absolutely everything and I won't even notice what events are going on).

So:

1. Is there a way to run system notifications off the log file? e.g. make it notify on every new line to the file?
2. Assuming that is possible, could I then filter only to display the lines starting with "Deleting", "Uploading" or other beginnings for notifications I want?

I am guessing there's no GUI tool to do this (notifications settings show no options for such customisation)... but maybe some kind of shell script reading the log file and sending relevant lines to the system notification app somehow? And then maybe making shell script run on startup or also via systemd?

Comment: https://github.com/birdie-github/useful-scripts/blob/master/dmesg-notify

Sorry, I'm not in a mood of adjusting it for you. This one took me a lot of work already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, for GUI notifications, you can use [`notify-send`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/notify-send.1.html). The "standard" way to run it is `notify-send <summary> [body]`, and you could change the expiration time, the urgency, category etc.

Now, in order to notify of every new line that appears in some log file, you could run something such as:

```
tail -n -0 -f <log file> | while read line; do notify-send "Notification from <log file>" "$line"; done
```

`tail -n -0 -f <log file>` will show any new lines appended to the file (ignoring the beginning of the file), and the the `while` loop will send a GUI notification to your display of every line.

If you want to filter specific lines, just add `grep` to the `tail` command. For instance, if you want to display the lines starting with "Deleting", "Uploading":

```
tail -n -0 -f <log file> | grep --line-buffered -e ^Deleting -e ^Uploading | while read line; do notify-send "Notification from <log file>" "$line"; done
```

The `--line-buffered` flag will ensure that `grep` will output line matching the patterns as soon as they appear, without buffering further.

Of course, inside the `while` loop you can add addition logic, depending on the content of `$line` to change the `notify-send` parameters according to the content (change urgency, expiration etc).

#### Update

Only after posting the answer, I noticed that [@ArtemS.Tashkinov](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/686708/run-linux-mint-ubuntu-debian-gnome-system-notifications-from-log-file-text#comment1298113_686708) posted in the comments a [script](https://github.com/birdie-github/useful-scripts/blob/master/dmesg-notify) from github that's doing more or less what I suggested, only it's reading the data from `journalctl` instead of a file. You could look there to take more ideas.

Comment: This looks like EXACTLY what I want... however I can't seem to get the shell script to even tail a log file... I open the log file in text editor (xe) and each time I save with new lines tail doesn't find them/output them. If I can get past that it should work?! (nb thanks!!!)

Comment: @the_t_test_1, I assume those logs are usually not edited by an editor, but that there's something that adding lines to them. In order to test it properly, just append the lines to the end of the log file: `echo "New line" >> <log file>"`. In addition, you can use `-F` instead of `-f` to your `tail` command in case there's some kind of log rotating, and the file might get recreated with the same name but different inode.

Comment: OMG it works. Thank you! Now I just need to find out how to ensure the shell script is always running as some kind of process. Should I just put it in startup apps, or some kind of fancy systemd thing?

Comment: I don't think it matters, just make sure it runs under your account (and not as root), and the you have the display set (see [@ArtemS.Tashkinov's script](https://github.com/birdie-github/useful-scripts/blob/master/dmesg-notify) to get a general sense on how it should look like in case the script is executed as root).